# Button is not being hide after clickable

Tags: java, button

I'm trying to hide the button after it is clicked, but it's not working for me.

This is my code:

```
final Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        ToDoList.list_list.add(names.get(position));
        button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        //names.remove(position);
        //refresh the adapter of the listview
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

Comment: try button.setVisibility(0);

Comment: Not working @ShreyasSarvothama

Comment: do you see error or just not working or it crashed? `button.setVisibility(0)`

Comment: @ShreyasSarvothama there's an error even with setting to 0

Comment: Please post the rest of the code.